# Search for Keyword in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

-Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

-Sheet2
[image: Sheet2]

I have set of different Keywords around 300 words, which i want to search in a sheet which has more than 3000 records. If found, i just want to identify which row has search keyword.

Eg :

Sheet 1 (Where keywords needs to searched):

- List item
- Row 1 Num: 8956875  ID: 999 Account: 567895 This customer is our customer.
- Row 2 Num: 895  ID: 111 Account: 0 This customer is not our customer.
- Row 3 Num: 596  ID: 222 Account: 0 This customer is not  our customer.
- Row 4 Num: 123  ID: 333 Account: 0 This customer is not  our customer.
- Row 5 Num: 56565 ID: 444 Account: 0  This customer is not our customer.

Sheet 2: (Key word repository)

- 8957075   -- Not found
- 8956875   -- Found in Row 1
- 8956975   -- Not found
- 8955875

Comment: It is not clear to me the structure of the data in Sheet1. Row1 is a text containing the value "Num: 8956875 ID: 999 Account: 567895 This customer is our customer. " or the text is in columns, so Row1 Column1[Num]: "8956875" Row1 Column2[ID]: "999" etc.? A picture would help.

Comment: Sorry, about not being clear.

Comment: @user434853 Please add any attempt/research you have done so far. We can help to solve a *code-related* issue or answer a question you have, but SO is not a free code writing site.

Comment: No problem! ;-) The strategy that I would use is to have a column in Sheet1 where I extract the customer num from each row in columnA. You can do it with MID and FIND function. Then in Sheet 2 with the function MATCH you can have the number of the line (pay attention to formats, i.e. MID returns a text). If you need further help please post another comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about repeats, use `FIND` in combination with `SEQUENCE`.

For example:

`=MAX(IFERROR(FIND(O1,$I$1:$I$4)*SEQUENCE(ROWS($I$1:$I$4))/FIND(O1,$I$1:$I$4),0))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would this do? `=IFERROR("Found in row "&MATCH(" "&'Sheet2'!A2&" ",'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A6,0),"Not found")`